# Spark Pivot in Group without aggregation

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, rdd

I have this DataFrame:

| id | name | q1_w | q1_x | q1_y | q1_z | q2_w | q2_x | q2_y | q2_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | valw | valx | valy | valz |
| 2 | BBBB | del1 | del2 | del3 | del4 | delw | delx | dely | delz |
| 3 | CCCC | sol1 | sol2 | sol3 | sol4 | null | null | null | null |

Trying to convert to this DataFrame:

| id | name | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| 1 | AAAA | valw | valx | valy | valz |
| 2 | BBBB | del1 | del2 | del3 | del4 |
| 2 | BBBB | delw | delx | dely | delz |
| 3 | CCCC | sol1 | sol2 | sol3 | sol4 |

What DataFrame transformation can help me with this `WITHOUT` converting to RDD?

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns in your source dataframe remains constant or same then you could just perform two separate transforations of selecting the columns and renaming it and then doing Union of the two dataframe and you could get the output that you want.

```
//source Data creation
val df = Seq((1,"AAAA","val1","val2","val3","val4","valw","valx","valy","valz"),(2,"BBBB","del1","del2","del3","del4","delw","delx","dely","delz"),(3,"CCCC","sol1","sol2","sol3","sol4",null,null,null,null)).toDF("id","name","q1_w","q1_x","q1_y","q1_z","q2_w","q2_x","q2_y","q2_z")
//creating first dataframe  with required columns and renaming them
val df1 = df.select("id","name","q1_w","q1_x","q1_y","q1_z").filter($"q1_w".isNotNull).filter($"q1_x".isNotNull).filter($"q1_y".isNotNull).filter($"q1_z".isNotNull).withColumnRenamed("q1_w","w").withColumnRenamed("q1_x","x").withColumnRenamed("q1_y","y").withColumnRenamed("q1_z","z")
//creating second dataframe  with required columns and renaming them
val df2 = df.select("id","name","q2_w","q2_x","q2_y","q2_z").filter($"q2_w".isNotNull).filter($"q2_x".isNotNull).filter($"q2_y".isNotNull).filter($"q2_z".isNotNull).withColumnRenamed("q2_w","w").withColumnRenamed("q2_x","x").withColumnRenamed("q2_y","y").withColumnRenamed("q2_z","z")
//union first and the second dataframe and you would get the output that is required.
val finaldf = df1.union(df2)
```

You can see the output as below:
[image]